# How to remove all remote branch files and freshly commit local files?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I messed something up with git. I have a remote `develop` branch in bitbucket that I want to remove all files from and then to commit/push files freshly from the local repository. How can I do that? I can't remove and recreate branch itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your local environment is good, you can `git push --force origin develop`, it serves [this very purpose](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---force).

Comment: does it delete files that are in remote repository and no more in local?

Comment: Yes, it'll update the state of remote repository along what's on your local branch(es)