# How to Overwrite remote branch with local branch in Bitbucket using command?

Tags: git, bitbucket

when i merged the local branch with remote, i found a lot of conflicts. I just want to overwrite remote branch with local. All changes of local should be applied on remote branch, so i just want to reset remote branch with new changes on local.

Comment: Hi Rabia and welcome to SO :-) Maybe check [this arguably similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430204/how-to-remove-all-remote-branch-files-and-freshly-commit-local-files/) asked yesterday.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RomainValeri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using a force push, e.g.

```
git push --force origin your_branch
```

Note that this will completely overwrite the remote branch with whatever you have locally.  Therefore, this also means that you will be rewriting the remote history.  You should probably *not* do this if the `your_branch` branch is shared by anyone other than yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Thanks for guiding me, i am new to stack overflow